# how to deep link to open default phone app in react native to call a person

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to open the default phone app from my react native app on a button press. when I searched the web I came to know about the deep linking.
As I'm new to react native I don't have an idea how this works. So can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `canOpenUrl()` to handle errors and then `openUrl('tel:string_of_the_number_to_call')`, something like this:

```
      const phoneNumber = '1232456';
      Linking.canOpenURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`)
        .then(supported => {
          if (!supported) {
            // handle the error
          } else {
            return Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`);
          }
        })
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just include the piece of code I posted in the function that handles the button press. Pass it the phone number you want, not just that fake const I used. That's all :)